# Non-standard dynamic system

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, optimal-control

I need to design a control to the following system dynamic:

y[k+1] = A x[k] + B u[k].

Notice that this system is different from the classical model: x[k+1] = A x[k] + B u[k].

I would like to know if there is anything about this system in the literature.

Thanks!

Comment: Your system has no dynamics?

Comment: your system is missing the dynamics of $x$. It is very probable that the problem formulation is not complete.

Comment: @Arastas well, $x$ could be just seen as a second input, so it would be just a (very confusing) way for writing the dynamics $y[k + 1] = B' v[k]$ with $B' = \begin{bmatrix}A & B \end{bmatrix}$ and $v[k] = \begin{bmatrix} x[k] \\ u[k] \end{bmatrix}$ where $v[k]$ is just the input at time $k$.